# Как вытащить множество подзначений из строки с помощью регулярных выражений?

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Допустим у меня есть строка `"100500<foo=100>some_text<foo=42><foo=2017>moar_text69"`. 
Нужно с помощью регулярных выражений и питона вытащить значение в тегах, т.е. `100, 42, 2017`

Мои попытки:

Использование `groups()` возвращает лишь первое совпадение, т.е. 100

```
 pattern = re.compile(r'<foo=(?P<name>[0-9]+)>')
 s = "100500<foo=100>some_text<foo=42><foo=2017> moar_text69"
 result = pattern.search(s).groups('name')
```

Использование `findall()` возвращает все, но не 100, 42, 2017, а `<foo=100>, <foo=42>, <foo=2017>`

Как добится желаемого поведения?

Comment: [`findall` возвращает желаемые значения](https://ideone.com/JWGlGD). Вы что-то не договариваете. Может, вместо `findall` вы использовали `finditer`?

Comment: Хм, действительно...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так работает:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'<foo=(\d+)>')
s = "100500<foo=100>some_text<foo=42><foo=2017> moar_text69"
result = pattern.findall(s)

print(result)
```

Результат:

> ['100', '42', '2017']